# Thread WPF start sequence of methods parallel

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to learn every day more C# and create a smal WPF Projekt. 
I don`t like to copy the whole cs file. I try to explain it in a much more easier way:
Ich have a windows with one Button and lot of Methods.

```
private void BtnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Methode1();
    Methode2();
    Methode3();
    Methode4();
    Methode5();
]
```

The methodes are for example this (The content of the methods are not relevant. Maybe good to know is, that the methods copy some files back and forth and the sourcePath is from a textbox of the GUI:

```
Methode1(){ File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath) }
Methode2(){ File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath) }
Methode3(){ File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath) }
Methode4(){ File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath) }
Methode5(){ File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath) }
```

What I like to do after the user has clicked on start in the background is:
Method 1 and 2 start
After methode 1 and 2 are finished continue with methode 3
After methode 3 is finished continue with methode 4 and 5

I heared about task, invoke, thread but I don't understand what is used when.
And I get everytime a **InvalidOperationException** if the method like to get the sourcePath of the Userinput:

Thanks a lot for all answers of you! :)

Comment: You are already calling the methods sequentially on the same thread, i.e. `Methode2` will be called once `Methode1` has finished and so on. Where do you get the exception? If you want to run methods in parallel, there is the [Parallel.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Comment: You cannot access UI elements directly from another thread than the UI thread. You have to use the dispatcher for the critical operation. Also read about `Task` and `Task.ContinueWith()`.

Comment: @BionicCode How I can initialize the  input of a textbox as a class variable?
I get "CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property"

Comment: Did I get you right, you want to show some initial text in the Text box? Generally from the error it looks like you're trying to initialize a field directly on declaration. This only works if the attribute is a static (class) attribute. This is because the instance itself is not created yet, which means the `this` reference is not available. But using a non static (instance) attribute requires to reference `this`. All this has to do with the class/instance construction rules of the C# compiler. You should either declare the member static or move the initialisation to the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Parallel.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=netcore-3.1) method to execute actions (possibly) in parallel:

```
Parallel.Invoke(Methode1, Methode2);
Methode3();
Parallel.Invoke(Methode4, Methode5);
```

The reason why you are getting an `InvalidOperationException` is probably that you are trying to access a `UIElement` on a background thread. This is not allowed. You should copy the value into a variable on the dispatcher thread, and then access the variable on the background thread:

```
string sourcePath, targetPath;
private void BtnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sourcePath = textBox.Text;
    targetPath = textBox2.Text;
    ...
}
```

You should also note that calling `File.Copy` on the UI thread will block and freeze your GUI during the time it takes to copy the file. A better approach would to make sure that you are always coping the files on a background thread, or copy the files [asynchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o).